# partitionkey and rowkey in azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I understand the benefit of a partition key in azure table storage. However, given my relational database background, I am a bit confused about how to retrieve an entity from azure table storage given just the rowkey. As far as I know, this is impossible. This means that I have to store the partition key/rowkey pair somewhere to just get the entity given the rowkey. Should I just introduce a 'sharding' table with one arbitrary partition key, which allows me to look up the partition key given the rowkey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible but will result in a table scan as described in this [section](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/#design-for-querying) of MSDN.

If you don't need multiple partitions then it is absolutely fine to use a single partition (e.g. using a constant) if your data isn't going to be enormous in size and needs the scalability of multiple partitions.

Another possible approach is to use your current `RowKey` as `PartitionKey` which would give you a highly scalable solution but would result in bad performance if you need to query ranges of rows.

The linked MSDN page talks about the pros and cons of both so I think with your knowledge about your specific problem domain you should be able to find a balanced solution.

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh508997.aspx#dft

Comment: I expect about 40 million or so 'entities' but may need to query ranges of rows. Catch 22 I guess ...